# Create 3rd vector while looping through 2 others

Tags: c++11, for-loop, vector

I'm totally newbie in C++ and I need to solve a problem with vectors. What I need is to merge two existing vectors and create third one. While I saw several answers, the difference here is I need vector #3 (values3) to contain not all values, but only those which are in both vectors #1 (values1) and #2 (values2). So, if integer 2 is in vector 1 but is not in vector 2, this number does not fit me. I should use a function provided below. Commented lines are which I don't know what to write in. Other lines are working.

```
void CommonValues(vector<MainClass> & values1, vector<MainClass> & values2, vector<MainClass> & values3)
{
    MainClass Class;
    string pav;
    int kiek;
    vector<MainClass>::iterator iter3; // ?
    for (vector<MainClass>::iterator iter1 = values1.begin(); iter1 != values1.end(); iter1++)
    {
        for (vector<MainClass>::iterator iter2 = values2.begin(); iter2 != values2.end(); iter2++)
        {
            if (iter1 == iter2)
            {
                pav = iter2->TakePav();
                iter3->TakePav(pav); // ?
                kiek = iter1->TakeKiek() + iter2->TakeKiek();
                iter3->TakeKie(kiek); // ?
                iter3++; // ?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is underspecified. E.g. are values1 and values2 sorted? Are you allowed to modify them. If values1 contains 10 twice and values2 only contains it once how many times should 10 be added to values3?

Comment: @user515430 Values are not sorted, I cannot modify them and if values are repeated, only once need to be added into new vector. Hope that specifies more of my help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort values1 and values2, then use std::intersection: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection

Your code at the moment won't work, among other problems, you are comparing iterator from vector 1 with iterator from vector 2, which doesn't make any sense. If you want to do it by looping, you should iterate through one vector and check if the value, for example *iter1, is in the 2nd vector.